# Xcode 8 Swift 3 Why does generateBoundaryString() generate an error?

Tags: url, request, swift3

The compiler says the method is an unresolved identifier.  What is wrong with: `var boundary=generateBoundaryString()`?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,
    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func sendToServer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/picSaver.php")

        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        var boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    }
```

The compiler complains that `generateBoundaryString()` is an unresolved identifier.  Why?

Comment: What error? And where is that function defined?

Comment: The error is: use of unresolved identifier.  I thought it was defined by Import UIKit, but it is defined below the IBAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generateBoundaryString()` function is not defined by UIKit, so it needs to be added.

Here's a suitable definition to add below the `IBAction`:

```
func generateBoundaryString() -> String {    
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)" 
}
```

Comment: See also comment above.

Comment: Why would you delete the answer? Then the question would already be answering itself.

Comment: So this *is* the answer?  It just looks like a statement of fact, as a response to Martin's question.  I'll make an edit that should clarify - but please check that I've got that right!